# How to add a value to existing value using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table named `products`.

```
Products
    Quantity
    5
```

I need to update `Quantity` by any value; for example, adding 3 to the current value, giving output like below:

```
Quantity
8
```

How can I write an SQL query to accomplish this?

Comment: update products set quantity = quantity + 3 ? (adding a where clause)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
update products
set quantity = quantity + 3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @table table(id int, quantity int)
insert into @table values(1, 5)

update @table
set quantity = quantity + 3
output inserted.quantity
```

Assuming that you actually wanted the value outputted. Don't forget any where clauses that may be needed

Answer (score 0):

Jus in case, for string value, it should be as follows :

```
update products
set quantity = concat(quantity, '3')
```