# Pos inventory system

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am making an inventory system but the problem is:

Database: ItemName, Quantity

ItemName: Anything
Quantity: 10

Now if I input something on my program like:

ItemName: Anything
Quantity : 20

The data on my database should be

ItemName: Anything
Quantity :30

But in my case it's just creating another line and displaying the output that I input on my program .

I'm using Visual Basic 2010

```
   Dim str as String
   str = "SELECT * FROM Table_name"
   If ItemName.text = str then
      str = "Update Table_name set ItemName=?,Quantity = Quantity+Quantity.text Where ID = ?"
  End if
```

and the problem about this query is, it can update the quantity though but all of the items on my database will be the same output as what I input in my program, for example

```
Database-ItemName  Quantity
A                  10 
b                  10
```

Now if i input C and 20 on my program the result will be:

```
Database-Itemname  Quantity
C                  30 
C                  30 
C                  20
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add some of the current code that creates this problem. As is your question is too broad to answer

Comment: In order to update the existing row in the database, you do not use an INSERT statement, but an UPDATE.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396119/how-to-add-a-value-to-existing-value-using-sql-query

Comment: Well i created thid kind of of query please just correct me .

Comment: @Steve sir can you help me now . I post my query already pretty please

Comment: @TonyHinkle sir i didnt use the insert query